# Why does ProGet handle leading 0's in build numbers differently from nuget.org?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-server, proget

When I use `nuget.exe` to install [Moq 4.2.1502.911](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/4.2.1502.911) using nuget.org (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/) as the source, the folder name is `Moq.4.2.1502.0911`.

When I upload the same package to a ProGet server and try to use `nuget.exe` to install that package, the folder name is `Moq.4.2.1502.911`.

Visual Studio is able to successfully use the nuget.org package, but not the ProGet package. This is probably because the reference to `Moq.dll` that is automatically added to the `.csproj` file uses the folder name with the 0 (`Moq.4.2.1502.0911`).

Looking into the `.nuspec` file, the `<version>` node is `<version>4.2.1502.0911</version>`, which matches the folder name when installing from nuget.org.

Why does ProGet handle the package differently than nuget.org?

Comment: What version of nuget.exe are you using, and also what version of ProGet? It is possible that this issue has been fixed in the latest release.

Comment: ProGet: Version 3.3.5; NuGet.exe: 2.8.60318.667.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this problem should be resolved in v3.3.11 of the v3.3 line, and the fix is also included with the latest at this current time, v3.5.7